# Using dijkstra_path function in networkx library

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, shortest-path, dijkstra, adjacency-matrix

I'm using `networkx` library to find shortest path between two nodes using `dijkstra` algo as follows

```
import networkx as nx

A = [[0, 100, 0, 0 , 40, 0],
     [100, 0, 20, 0, 0, 70],
     [0, 20, 0, 80, 50, 0],
     [0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 30],
     [40, 0, 50, 0, 0, 60],
     [0, 70, 0, 30, 60, 0]];

print(nx.dijkstra_path(A, 0, 4))
```

In the above code I'm using matrix directly, But library requires graph to be created as follows

```
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.add_node(<node>)
G.add_edge(<node 1>, <node 2>)
```

It is very time consuming to create matrix by using above commands. Is there any way to give input as weighted matrix to the `dijkstra_path` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert your adjacency matrix to a `numpy` matrix with `np.array`.
Then you can simply create your graph with [`from_numpy_matrix`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix.html).

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = [[0, 100, 0, 0 , 40, 0],
     [100, 0, 20, 0, 0, 70],
     [0, 20, 0, 80, 50, 0],
     [0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 30],
     [40, 0, 50, 0, 0, 60],
     [0, 70, 0, 30, 60, 0]]

a = np.array(A)
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(a)

print(nx.dijkstra_path(G, 0, 4))
```

Output:

```
[0, 4]
```

Side note: you can check the graph edges with the following code.

```
for edge in G.edges(data=True):
    print(edge)
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, {'weight': 100})
(0, 4, {'weight': 40})
(1, 2, {'weight': 20})
(1, 5, {'weight': 70})
(2, 3, {'weight': 80})
(2, 4, {'weight': 50})
(3, 5, {'weight': 30})
(4, 5, {'weight': 60})
```